# Compiling vim from source - fails to configure with libncurses6

Tags: vim, compilation, python-3.x, ncurses, opensuse

I have recently started moving to vim as my main development environment, and I wanted to write some plugins for it in Python. I soon discovered that on my opensuse, vim is distributed without python support so I proceeded to get the source and try to compile it. 
Calling

```
./configure --enable-python3interp
```

returns an error that ncurse is not installed. Since on OpenSuse libncurses6 provides that, I proceeded to do this:

```
./configure --enable-python3interp --with-tlib=libncurses6
```

In this case I get the following error:

```
checking --with-tlib argument... libncurses6
checking for linking with libncurses6 library... configure: error: FAILED
```

I am not sure what to do. I have installed all ncurse related packages just in case, still no luck.
My OS is OpenSuse 11.4 and I would prefer to use the python 3.x interpreter by default.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `ls /usr/lib | grep ncurses` give? Maybe change `--with-tlib=libncurses6` to `--with-tlib=ncurses6`?

Comment: Actually it does not output anything. The solution below fixed the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [OpenSUSE build](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file?file=vim.spec&package=vim&project=openSUSE%3AFactory%3AARM&srcmd5=4728c958abd09ab61ec197cdf26dc871) service, you should have the ncurses-devel package installed and run configure using `--with-tlib=ncurses`.

Answer (score 0):

On mingw:

```
mingw-get install mingw32-libpdcurses
configure --with-tlib=pdcurses
```

Answer (score 0):

yum install ncurses-devel

Try again ./configure